Customize TextField when focus throw dirty elements
I want to add widgets (like extra border) when the text field is focused.
I've simplified my problem.
class CustomTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomTextField({super.key});

  @override
  State<CustomTextField> createState() => _CustomTextFieldState();
}

class _CustomTextFieldState extends State<CustomTextField> {
  final _widgetStatesController = WidgetStatesController();
  bool isFocused = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _widgetStatesController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        isFocused = _widgetStatesController.value.contains(WidgetState.focused);
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _widgetStatesController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(final BuildContext context) {
    Widget textField = TextField(
      statesController: _widgetStatesController,
    );

    if (isFocused) {
      textField = Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
        child: textField,
      );
    }

    return textField;
  }
}

When I tap on a text field, I have this error:
The following assertion was thrown while rebuilding dirty elements:
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 5212 pos 12: '!_dirty': is not true.


I don't know how this simplifies your problem, have you tried using FocusNode though ? Below an example
class _CustomTextFieldState extends State<CustomTextField> {
  final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _focusNode.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _focusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        TextField(
          focusNode: _focusNode,
        ),
        if (_focusNode.hasFocus) const Text('isFocused'),
      ],
    );
  }
}


I chose the wrong example.
I need to add a border and padding around the text field.

As long as you have the _focusNode.hasFocus information you can do whatever you want. Wrap the TextField with a DecoratedBox and add border with width 0 when it has focus and >0 when it doesn't (just an example).

Try below code
class _CustomTextFieldState extends State<CustomTextFieldFocus> {
  bool isFocused = false;
  final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  void initState() {
    _focusNode.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _focusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(final BuildContext context) {
    Widget textField = Material(
      child: TextField(
        focusNode: _focusNode,
      ),
    );

    if (isFocused) {
      textField = Column(
        children: [
          textField,
          const Text('isFocused'),
        ],
      );
    }

    return textField;
  }
}


Try this one
class CustomTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomTextField({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CustomTextField> createState() => _CustomTextFieldState();
}

class _CustomTextFieldState extends State<CustomTextField> {
  final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();
  bool isFocused = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _focusNode.addListener(_onFocusChange);
  }

  void _onFocusChange() {
    setState(() {
      isFocused = _focusNode.hasFocus;
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _focusNode.removeListener(_onFocusChange);
    _focusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget textField = TextField(
      focusNode: _focusNode,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
        hintText: 'Enter text here',
      ),
    );

    if (isFocused) {
      textField = Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          textField,
          const SizedBox(height: 8),
          const Text('Field is focused', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)),
        ],
      );
    }

    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: AnimatedContainer(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
            color: isFocused ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
            width: isFocused ? 2.0 : 1.0,
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
        ),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
        child: textField,
      ),
    );
  }
}

